# How to create Android Instant App with latest android studio with existing app?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-instant-apps

Need help of creating Instant app for already existing app. when i checked all instant video tutorials are 4 or 5 years old including android developer site. Not available any tutorials or samples in latest android studio. if any one knows please share the details. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you have checked this [documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/google-play-instant/getting-started/instant-enabled-app-bundle). I managed to convert my existing app to an android instant app based on this.

If you find it hard to follow, perhaps you can attempt to create a hello world instant app before trying to convert.

It is actually just tweaking the manifest and gradle.

`implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-instantapps:17.0.0"`
for the gradle.

```
<manifest
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  ...
   android:targetSandboxVersion="2" ...>
   <dist:module dist:instant="true" />
    ...
</manifest>
```

add 2 lines into the manifest above.

Also do remember to go to Edit Configurations and enable the option `Deploy as instant app`.

If it still does not run, check your permissions set against those allowed for android instant apps.